# How to make a Horizontal form with deform 2?

Tags: python, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, deform

I am using [deform 2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/deform/2.0a2) together with Bootstrap 3, to render some forms, and I want to create a Horizontal form as shown [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal), but all of the examples on the [demo-site](http://deform2demo.repoze.org), is not examples of horizontal forms( with the label next to the input element).

I have tried using `form_class="form-horizontal"`, and `bootstrap_form_style="form-horizontal"`([deform_bootstrap](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/deform_bootstrap/0.2.9)). When using the above, it does add the class `form-horizontal`, however I dont just want to add a class to the form element.

How do I add the rest of the class names to the rest of the form to make it a horizontal form as is on the the [bootstrap site](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal)?

Comment: Someone made a demo site (http://deformretail.chromaticleaves.com/login) to showcase the new possibilities with deform2. It has horizontal forms and source code. HTH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out, in the deform templates(I over write them) I did:

**mapping_item.pt:**

```
<div tal:define="error_class error_class|field.widget.error_class;
                 description description|field.description;
                 title title|field.title;
                 oid oid|field.oid;
                 hidden hidden|field.widget.hidden;
                 category category|field.widget.category;
                 structural hidden or category == 'structural';
                 required required|field.required;"
     class="form-group  ${field.error and 'has-error' or ''} ${field.widget.item_css_class or ''}"
     title="${description}"
     id="item-${oid}"
     tal:omit-tag="structural"
     i18n:domain="deform">
  <!-- <div class="col-sm-12"> -->


  <label for="${oid}"
         class="control-label col-sm-3 col-md-3 ${required and 'required' or ''}"
         tal:condition="not structural"
         id="req-${oid}"
         >
    ${title}
  </label>
<div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9">
  <div tal:define="input_prepend field.widget.input_prepend | None;
                   input_append field.widget.input_append  | None"
       tal:omit-tag="not (input_prepend or input_append)"
       class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"
          tal:condition="input_prepend">${input_prepend}</span
    ><span tal:replace="structure field.serialize(cstruct).strip()"
    /><span class="input-group-addon"
            tal:condition="input_append">${input_append}</span>
  </div>

  <p class="help-block"
     tal:define="errstr 'error-%s' % field.oid"
     tal:repeat="msg field.error.messages()"
     i18n:translate=""
     tal:attributes="id repeat.msg.index==0 and errstr or
     ('%s-%s' % (errstr, repeat.msg.index))"
     tal:condition="field.error and not field.widget.hidden and not field.typ.__class__.__name__=='Mapping'">
    ${msg}
  </p>

   <p tal:condition="field.description and not field.widget.hidden"
     class="help-block" >
    ${field.description}
  </p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Notice in the `label` I added `col-sm-3 col-md-3`
Also I added a `<div>` with a class: `class="col-sm-9 col-md-9"`

This makes the item i.e.  label + input 'horizontal'(displays in the same line):
[image: label and input tag]

In `form.pt`, in the form tag I added:

```
class="deform ${field.bootstrap_form_style | 'form-horizontal'}
```

I also do when define the form layout:

```
agent = colander.SchemaNode(
    colander.String(),
    validator=agent_validator,
    widget=widget.AutocompleteInputWidget(
        size=40,
        style="width: 300px",
        min_length=3,
        values=url,
        css_class="form-control"
        ),
    title="Agent*")
```

I hope this is helpful.